# htaccess redirect dynamic old file to new File

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dynamic

I have upgraded my website and changed some locations of the files. One part is for to create feeds. So before i used to have this:

```
mydomain/plugins/rss/feed.php?id=187
```

but now it became:

```
mydomain/feed.php?from=category&id=187
```

The only part that changes is the ID the from variable doesnt change. I tried it with this:

```
RewriteRule ^plugins/rss/feed.php?id=([0-9]+)$ feed.php?from=category&id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that doesnt work... Anyone an idea on how to redirect it to the new one??

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the **?** mark in the URI) in a `RewriteRule` command. But since it doesn't need to be changed, you won't need to mess with that. If you remove that check, your rule should work ok. Try changing it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^plugins/rss/feed.php /feed.php?from=category [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The flag `QSA` needs to be added here to append any existing query string, in this case, the `id=` part.

Comment: Are you able to get to `/feed.php?from=category&id=187` without a 403?

Comment: Hi Jon, I just made another rule for: rewriting search.php?what=search+whatever&type=1 to buscador.php?what=search+whatever&type=1 and i placed the following rule RewriteRule ^search.php$ /buscador.php [R=301,L,QSA] and this one is working... dont understand why the other one not. Maybe it is because of that the /plugins/rss/feed.php is located in a subdirectory and the new on in the root...

Comment: @user1566662 Not sure why you got a 403, it being in a subdirectory shouldn't matter unless you have other rules in the `/plugins/` or `/plugins/rss/` directories.